# Is this possible to do using SQL only?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables.
Table 1:

[image]

And Table 2:

[image]

The only thing I know about is ProductType `Base` which I use to get BatchId from Table1. Then I use all the BatchId's to get data from Table2.

More details:
The Table1 has data from many `ProductType` 's. I am interested in `Base`. Once I get all the `BatchId` 's for the `ProductType` `Base` I use those to get data from Table2. Table2 also has data for many `ProductType` 's. However they did not store it. They just stored the `BatchId` 's. The trouble is that `seal` step is logged against another system generated `BatchId` for a given `UnitNumber`.

Right now my query looks like:

```
SELECT 
    Id, 
    AssemblyStep, 
    BatchId, 
    UnitNumber, 
FROM Table2 
WHERE BatchId IN (SELECT DISTINCT BatchId FROM Table1 WHERE ProductType='Base') 
ORDER BY Id ASC
```

This works as shown in the green rows but I am not able to get the two rows which I have highlighted in red.

[image]

This is expected. However is there a clever way I can extract the full data for `UnitNumber` 8888 and 9999 from Table2 using some joins?

Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Also please only tag a *single* RDBMS.

Comment: What's the point of the `WHERE` clause if its too restrictive? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Can you JOIN on UnitNumber rather than BatchID?   You haven't described the meaning for UnitNumber so it may not be appropriate but for the sample data provided you could use it

Comment: @MartinCairney The last seal step will happen at end of the day and hence that data will appear much later. This script will be used to poll and pull data. I will be using SomeId from Table1 to track how many records I have processed. Once I have processed a record I will not process it again. Hence there is a chance I will miss out on the seal data which will be not there when I run the query. But will appear later at end of the day.

Comment: @HoneyBadger I added more details. It is a difficult one to describe. Let me know if something is missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the whole of table2 you just need a select * from table2

From what I see, table1 has no records where batchId = 222 so all table2 records with batchId 222 aren't supposed to show up.

EDIT

So if I understand this correctly, you also want table2 records where AssemblyStep = 'Seal' and UnitNumber is either 8888 or 9999

```
SELECT 
    Id, 
    AssemblyStep, 
    BatchId, 
    UnitNumber, 
FROM Table2 
WHERE BatchId IN (SELECT DISTINCT BatchId FROM Table1 WHERE ProductType='Base')
    OR
UnitNumber IN (Select DISTINCT UnitNumber FROM Table1 WHERE ProductType='Base') 
ORDER BY Id ASC
```

Comment: I maybe condensed and simplified the data too much. I added more details. It makes tables longer but more representative. Thanks having a look.

Comment: My list of problems is long. The AssemblyStep is hand entered into system and can be anything. I want to collect all the BatchIds whose ProductType is Base. Then from Table2 I want all the records for those BatchIds plus the records which has same UnitNumbers but whose BatchId might be different. I am not sure if I am doing a good job of explaining. Does the third table image help?

Comment: I believe I understand now, check out my latest edit. I'm not 100% sure if you only wanted this for 'seal' steps or if that was just a for-instance. But it's just one more small change if so.

Answer (score 0):

you should use LEFT JOIN instead of using WHERE Clause.
LEFT JOIN gives you the rows that returned null from the left table, but exists in the right table therefore you won't miss any rows if the join not returned all the results.

```
SELECT 
    T2.Id, 
    T2.AssemblyStep, 
    T2.BatchId, 
    T2. UnitNumber, 
FROM Table2 T2
LEFT JOIN Table1 T1 ON T1.BatchId = T2.BatchId
ORDER BY T2.Id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

### Simple solution

Right now, this will do what you want:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table2 
ORDER BY Id ASC
```

It seems you have some logic in mind that you would like to match up some combination of batch ID and Product Type to form the foreign key, instead of just using Product Type (which cannot be the foreign key if it is not in Table2) or the Batch ID (which you describe as relevant in the question, but hint is not based on your desired result).

### Selecting all actions for unit numbers returned by base:

If you want this:
(1) Get the BatchId from Table 1 for all rows where ProductType is Base, (2) Get the rows from table 2 for that batch
(3) Get all other rows from table 2 for the unit numbers generated by (2), regardless of the batch.

...with step (3) to ensure complete activities on any unit matching the "base" batch ID from table 1...

Then try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table2 
WHERE UnitNumber IN (SELECT UnitNumber FROM Table1 WHERE ProductType='Base')
ORDER BY Id ASC
```

Comment: I added more details. I think I condensed and simplified data too much. My apologies.

Comment: Ok. I am familiar with similar issues in manufacturing WIP data and system update lot/batch numbers so we should be able to get there. So do you want to do this (do I understand right?): (1) Get the BatchId from Table 1 for all rows where ProductType is Base, (2) Get the rows from table 2 for that batch, (3) Get all other rows from table 2 for the unit numbers generated by (2), regardless of the batch. I suspect your step 3 is to ensure complete activities on any unit matching the "base" batch ID from table 1, is this correct?

Comment: Yes. You captured it nicely. In short I want all events for UnitNumber 8888 and 9999 from Table2.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your sample data and output the joining condition is `BatchId`, so just this should work

```
select
    t2.Id, 
    t2.AssemblyStep, 
    t2.BatchId, 
    t2.UnitNumber
from
(select distinct unitnumber from Table1 where producttype='base') t1
join Table2 t2 on t2.unitnumber=t1.unitnumber
```